# Error trying to access a section on a page by clicking on a link that is on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am trying to access a section that is in my index.php page by clicking on a link that is in other pages ...
The link is in the navbar-menu, when I clicked on the link, it would take me to a section that is on my index.php page
Before, this worked very well but now it does not work well. When I click on my link, it takes me to another section, not to the section that I want.

This is my navbar-code:

```
       <li class="list_options_Li" id="first_li_main"><a href="leistungen.php" class="smoothScroll main_a">Leistungen</a></li>
            <li class="list_options_Li" id="second_li_main"><a href="referenzen.php" class="smoothScroll main_a">Referenzen</a></li>
            <li class="list_options_Li" id="third_li_main"><a href="https://nivamedia.ch/index.php#agentur" class="smoothScroll main_a">Agentur</a></li>
            <li class="list_options_Li" id="fourth_li_main"><a href="kontakt.php" class="smoothScroll main_a">Kontakt</a></li>
```

As you can see, this is the link on menu: href= "https://nivamedia.ch/index.php#agentur"

this is the section with id=agentur

[image]

And this is the code in of section agentur in index.php:

```
           <section id="agentur">

          <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                <div class="section-title" id="agentur_section_title">
                   <h2 class="heading" id="agentur_h1_title" style= "padding-top: 0px; font-size: 700 !important;">Nivamedia-Digital<br> Agentur in Aarau</h2>
                     <hr align=left style="width: 280px;">
                       </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                </div>
           </section>
```

When clicking on the link, that should take me to the section with id = agentur in index.php but that does not happen, instead, it takes me to the end of the page. Before that did not happen, the page worked very well, but now I have this error and I do not know where it came from.

Any ideas on how to solve this? I have reviewed my code and I see it very well.

To show you better, You can Go to this link: https://nivamedia.ch/referenzen.php and click on the menu option "Agentur", it should go to index.php#agentur but it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me (FF 63). Have you tried clearing your cache? Trying a different browser? Trying in incognito mode?

Also, it looks like your markup is broken. This can often lead to anchors not working (because the browser cannot recognise the anchor).
E.g. line 1510:

```
<p <i id="medium_icon_form1" class="icon-envelope medium-icon wow bounceIn" data-wow-delay="0.6s" style= "padding-right: 160px;"></i> E-Mail</p>
```

Comment: Even fixing that error in the <p> element does not work either. 
I have tried to limit the cache, I have tried it in another browser, and it is not working.

Comment: The interesting thing is that previously worked great. Two days ago it was working well, today it is not working, and I have not touched the code in these two days.

Comment: You still have a script tag between head and body tags (invalid). Please run your page through a validator and fix all the errors before checking again. Your code is broken in multiple places.

Comment: Ok, if it is not working with the Agentur section, it should not work with the other sections either. But if I try to access the section New projekt (the one before agentur) from other pages, it works well...Why?

Comment: The point of having valid code is that the behaviour of the browser's rendering becomes predictable. If the code is not valid, then the browser will handle the code in different and often unpredictable ways. Your question is exactly why you want to have valid markup - so you can determine why one case works and why one case doesn't.

Comment: Well I have corrected some errors that came out in my debugger, I have tried again but it still does not work.

Comment: You still have markup errors: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fnivamedia.ch%2Findex.php If you really want to get a quick solution, you need to post a minimal, complete, verifiable solution: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fnivamedia.ch%2Findex.php

Comment: The problem was solved. This was in a JS library that was broken. I did download it again and after that, The site is working well again.